# How to analyse gamma ray spectra?

Tags: experimental-physics, radioactivity, statistics, data-analysis, gamma-rays

I have recently done an experiment using gamma radiation and am now at a loss as to how to analyse the data I acquired. I have a background spectrum and a spectrum from a radioactive sample and need to perform a statistical analysis that *'convincingly shows that the amount of radioactive substance has increased'*.

I have considered taking the background spectrum away from the sample spectrum but don't really know what to do with it from that point onward. I've also had suggested to me that performing a Gaussian fit on each of the peaks would be useful although I am unsure how to calculate significance from that.

Any advice would be very much appreciated!

EDIT: For more context, this is for a write-up for a four-day undergraduate lab. There was no indication that I should be using anything more complex than R or Matlab for the analysis.

Comment: Is this a homework question? If so, then it should be tagged as such.

Comment: It's a question about an experiment I have done for which I now have to analyse the data and write a report, so not what I considered a homework exercise, but if it would be more appropriate to tag it as such I can do so?

Comment: You should be careful with how you analyze that data. [Software for analyzing gamma-ray spectra is known to occasionally be buggy](http://www.underhanded-c.org/#summary).

Comment: I do not think this qualifies as a homework-like question. Your original tags were fine. I have rolled back the edits to v1.

Comment: Possibly [Cross Validated SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) is more suitable than Physics SE, because your question is about data analysis and hypothesis testing rather than experimental technique.

Comment: -1 Have you done an internet search using your title? Google returns several useful-looking items. We expect you to make some effort to do your own research before asking here.

Comment: @sammy Yes, I have done some research before coming here. However, I have found the information online to be too complex for my current level of understanding and also probably far more in depth than what I actually need to be using, and I'm only posting here because I'm very confused. Thank you for the suggestion about Cross Validated SE, I will look into that.

Comment: If you are still hoping for advice here, it would be helpful to have more details about your experiment : what you were measuring and what results you got. Lab scripts usually provide enough information to do the data analysis. What exactly does it say? Have you asked the lab supervisor/assistant for help, or other students who have done the experiment?

Comment: Either R or Matlab would be fine for this job.: they are exactly what I meant by  a *"statistical or data analysis tool kit"*. They are both perfectly capable of performing arithmetic on tuples of data on a bin-by-bin basis and of fitting a function to a series represented by such a tuple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do want to do a back-ground subtracted analysis, but there are a few things to keep in mind before you begin.

1. You're looking for a change in activity over time, so you need to look a *multiple* background-subtracted spectra.
2. Background subtraction has to be normalized to live time (and separately for each subtraction unless your live-times are identical).
3. Peak fitting (on properly background subtracted data) is one way of estimating the total number of events in the peak (i.e. proportional to the area of the peak). A Gaussian is a good function for devices with poor or modest energy resolution, but for high resolution devices fitting a Lorentzian is better than a Gaussian.

There are dozens of software package to help you with this kind of analysis (just about every commercial supplier of detectors ships one with the tools), or you can do it with essentially any statistical or data analysis tool kit. Frankly the nitty-gritty of running a particular software package is the least important thing about the assignment: this is about understanding how the data should be treated and conclusions drawn, not about what you type or where you click.

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a fitting code called SAMPO that would fit a whole spectrum. I'm fairly sure the software is still around and being used. What device did you use to generate the visible spectrum? The unit may have its own fitting software. SAMPO would fit the background and fit the peaks with a Gaussian distribution. The parameters wear physics based i.e, they woulda depend on the energy og the gamma-ray and how peak with increases versus energy. I suggest you do a google search to better understand the background and peak formation of a gamma ray spectrum.

That being said, if these are fairly small peaks in a relatively flat region of the spectrum, a linear background should suffice and geak intensity can be obtained by adding the number of counts in each channel and subtracting the background count from each channel. Or more accurately, fit each peak with a gaussian distribution and get area that way.

I assume you used a germanium or silicon detector and that gamma ray energies in the 1 MeV range? Lower energy gamma rays probably have a much large energy dependent background calling for an advanced fitting routine like the one found in SAMPO. A quick google serch for SAMPO and gamma rays found several links.

You mentioned you have a background spectrum. If so you could try normalizing it and then subtracting it from your data spectrum. You must of had something to monitor those spectras, either time or counts from a monitor. So you can very carefully normalize the background spectrum and then just subtract it channel per channel.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did indeed use a Germanium detector looking at energies up to around 2.5MeV. Unfortunately I no longer have access to the equipment I used (see added context above) so wouldn't be able to use any fitting software it came with. I will have a look at SAMPO as you suggested, although I most likely will end up doing a simpler analysis following your ideas.

Comment: @Ellie25 Since you added the part of an undergraduate lab, many of my suggestions would be severe overkill! lol.  But subtracting the background is a definite yes.

Comment: Sorry, should definitely have mentioned that at the start! But any form of direction is helpful at this stage!